# which google map api is used to add my business place marker to google map programmatically from app

Tags: google-places-api, google-maps-android-api-2

We developed app for warehouse listing and management. We want to add business place marker / Warehouse to google map programmatically through api from our android application, so that any person can search that warehouse in their google map. which google map api required for that?

Perhaps these are related to my problem but now not exist
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/add/json?key=YOUR_KEY
https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/add-place

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no API to add places to Google Maps. The URLs you point our are related to a very old API what was [deprecated in 2017 and shut down in 2018](https://developers.google.com/maps/deprecations#place_add_and_place_delete_june_30_2017_-_june_30_2018).